# Approximately how long do bacteria live for?

Tags: bacteriology

I would like to know how many days or years do the bacteria live approximately.

Comment: I think this depends on species and particular conditions. E.G. An amp resistant strain of bacteria would be fine if you grew it on an amp plate and a non amp resistant one would die. Plus how much room does it have?

Comment: room? What you mean?

Comment: The amount of space they have to grow.

Comment: a human body you mean?

Comment: Um, no. I mean where is it growing and how much space does it have to grow - I.e. is it a huge area or are they confined to a Petrie dish? - also, how much food do they have? Are they arobic or anaerobic?

Comment: Sure arobic and what about a huge area 1-6 meteres

Comment: @Orphee Are you trying to ask how long pathogenic bacteria live for in the human body? Because that's a completely different question

Comment: Yes, I mean how long bacteria (pathogenic) live in the human body (aproximatly).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They're effectively immortal, albeit in a Phoenix-rising-from-the-ashes sort of way.

In general, a bacterial cell will divide as soon as it's biochemically able to do so, leaving behind two daughter cells. Neither daughter cell is actually the same as the mother cell, so in one sense the mother cell will have "died". On the other hand, the daughter cells are genetically identical to the mother cell and all of the physical material present in each of the daughter cells at the moment right after they split came from the mother cell.

Comment: It should be noted, however, that cell viability relies on a number of different factors.

Comment: I love how you describe them as immortals. :-)

Comment: related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21111/do-bacteria-die-of-old-age