# What is the most primitive organism that can die of aging?

Tags: physiology

I know that simple organisms containing of just few cells have no mechanism of dying because of aging. I guess, they typically die due to being out of food or due to becoming someone else's food.

Leaving aside the numerous theories of what can be the origin of such phenomenon as aging, I'm asking a simple question: what is the most primitive organism known so far which has the feature of aging and (as a consequence) dying, even if the environment is perfect?

Comment: I feel it's essentially a dupe of question mentioned by Remi, as OP could easily call bacteria simplest organisms.

Answer (score 0):

The adjective primitive is undefined, at least when comparing extant species. We have all gone through almost 4 billions years of evolution.

I would suspect you would consider a bacteria quite primitive though, so note that bacteria appears to age (see [Do bacteria die of old age?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21111/do-bacteria-die-of-old-age)).